# Can OPC-UA Server override timeouts and other parameters over connected client?

Tags: node.js, opc-ua, node-opcua

I created an OPC-UA server based on Node-OPCUA and node.js and several clients have wrong or empty parameters when connecting. This causes malfunctions on clients side.

Is it possible for server to override or correct the client configuration parameters so it works correctly even when the client is wrongly defined?

I am particularly interested in overriding session and connection timeouts.

Clients may disruptively disconnect, so the server does no close that connection. How do I get rid of those zombie connections? Sessions are usually closed due to timeout, but not connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because it's again the OPC-UA protocol. The client should be able to open a connection with its own parameters.
If you detect that the client is wrongly configured you should throw a ServiceException instead.